# Python Loop, .remove, and List Exercise

Tags: python, loops

So we have an exercise that we are giving to the children and we need to use a list(or array), as well as the '.remove()' method, and a loop.

I have the following code and the code isn't working.

```
usernames = [
    'Steph','JHG','Greg','Matt','Rodney','David',
    'Chris','Sally','Gemma','Pam','Daniel','JHG',
    'JHG','Ishmael','Sam', 'JHG','Jacob'
]
for i in range(0,3):
    for name in usernames:
        usernames.remove('JHG')
print(usernames)
```

## Checker

```
print (
'Success! all the JHG values have been deleted from the list, onto the next!')
```

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Or as a `while` loop:

```
while 'JHG' in usernames:
    usernames.remove('JHG')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in usernames:
    if name == 'JHG':
         usernames.remove(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using a loop to remove all instances of 'JHG'. Since the for loop loops a bunch of times (3 times for the outer loop, and as many names as you have in the list for the inner loop), you're basically removing 'JHG' a bunch times. It works fine the first three times, removes all 'JHG's, but the fourth time it fails because there are no 'JHG's left to remove!

If you want students to use a loop, perhaps you can check if the names in username equal 'JHG', then remove it.

```
for name in usernames:
  if name == 'JHG':
    usernames.remove(name)
```

Comment: "It works fine the first time, removes all 'JHG's, but the second time it fails because there are no 'JHG's left to remove!"  <-- usernames.remove('JHG') removes only one occurence of 'JHG'

Comment: You're right, I messed that up. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Simple and quickly:

```py
usernames = [name for name in usernames if x != 'JHG']
```

Comment: one liners are neat, but I would not consider them simple for kids.